# SQL Server query to get continues occurrences

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I came across a requirement were I have my source table like,

```
Machine_Name|    Time             |   Alarm 
------------|---------------------|---------
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 05:15 |   0     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 05:30 |   1     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 05:45 |   1     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:00 |   0     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:15 |   1     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:30 |   1     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:45 |   1     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:00 |   1     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:15 |   1     
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:30 |   1     
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 05:15 |   0     
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 05:30 |   0     
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 05:45 |   1     
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:00 |   1     
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:15 |   1     
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:30 |   1     
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:45 |   0     
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 07:00 |   1
```

Above table stores details of difference machines installed in a facility and its 'Issue Alarm' status for each period(each 15 min interval).

Now I need to calculate relevancy of this Alarms. For any single Alarm the relevancy is 25%. If a machine raised alarm for 4 consecutive periods(1 hrs.) then it archives the max relevancy 100%.

If alarm raised for more than 4 consecutive periods (1 hrs.) then the relevancy stays same 100% .

The expected result set from the above source table is as follows,

```
Machine_Name|    Time             |   Alarm |  Alert_Relevancy(%)
------------|---------------------|---------|---------------
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 05:15 |   0     |  0 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 05:30 |   1     |  25 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 05:45 |   1     |  50 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:00 |   0     |  0 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:15 |   1     |  25 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:30 |   1     |  50 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:45 |   1     |  75 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:00 |   1     |  100 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:15 |   1     |  100
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:30 |   1     |  100
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 05:15 |   0     |  0 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 05:30 |   0     |  0 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 05:45 |   1     |  25 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:00 |   1     |  50 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:15 |   1     |  75 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:30 |   1     |  100 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:45 |   0     |  0 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 07:00 |   1     |  25
```

And it will be great if I can also get a query to select only those Alarm Series where it is raised continuously for minimum 4 times (relevancy reached 100 ).

The expected second result set would be as follows, were I have removed any alarm series which not 1 for consecutively at least 4 times.

```
Machine_Name|    Time             |   Alarm |  Alert_Relevancy(%)
------------|---------------------|---------|---------------
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:15 |   1     |  25 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:30 |   1     |  50 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 06:45 |   1     |  75 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:00 |   1     |  100 
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:15 |   1     |  100
Mac1        |    2016-11-22 07:30 |   1     |  100
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 05:45 |   1     |  25 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:00 |   1     |  50 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:15 |   1     |  75 
Mac2        |    2016-11-22 06:30 |   1     |  100
```

Comment: What DBMS? if MSSQL 2012+ you can use lag and lead functions, if not you can use CTE's for this.  EDIT: assuming you are from your previous question..

Comment: You have just chosen a solution that goes record by record over a set based solution.

Comment: Hi Mortb, Sorry I did not include the content with what I tried first. My bad. I tried with CTE method but was unable to reach the exact result as my anchor record was set wrongly. But later LukStorms posted the exact solution that I was looking for. I will make sure I include the problem snippet with the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      Machine_Name
           ,time
           ,Alarm
           ,case when alarm_seq >= 4 then 4 else alarm_seq end * 25

from       (select      *
                       ,sum (Alarm) over 
                        (
                            partition by    Machine_Name,group_id 
                            order by        time
                        )                           as alarm_seq

            from       (select      *
                                   ,count (nullif(alarm,1)) over 
                                    (
                                        partition by    Machine_Name 
                                        order by        time
                                    )   as group_id

                        from        t
                        ) t
            ) t
```

---

```
select      Machine_Name
           ,time
           ,Alarm
           ,case when alarm_seq >= 4 then 4 else alarm_seq end * 25

from       (select      *
                       ,sum (Alarm) over 
                        (
                            partition by    Machine_Name,group_id 
                            order by        time
                        )                           as alarm_seq

                       ,sum (Alarm) over 
                        (
                            partition by    Machine_Name,group_id 
                        )                           as alarms

            from       (select      *
                                   ,count (nullif(alarm,1)) over 
                                    (
                                        partition by    Machine_Name 
                                        order by        time
                                    )   as group_id

                        from        t
                        ) t
            ) t

where       alarms >= 4
        and alarm = 1
```

Comment: Hi Markovitz, Going with your solution as the CTE solution is consuming more time to produce the result when applied on a large source. Thanks.

Comment: @RonyVarghes - sounds like a good move... Can you please share the execution times for both solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Using a CTE with row_number and a recursive CTE

The SQL uses a table variable for demonstration purposes.

```
declare @SourceTable table (Machine_Name varchar(4), [Time] datetime, Alarm bit);

insert into @SourceTable values
('Mac1','2016-11-22 05:15',0),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 05:30',1),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 05:45',1),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 06:00',0),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 06:15',1),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 06:30',1),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 06:45',1),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 07:00',1),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 07:15',1),
('Mac1','2016-11-22 07:30',1),
('Mac2','2016-11-22 05:15',0),
('Mac2','2016-11-22 05:30',0),
('Mac2','2016-11-22 05:45',1),
('Mac2','2016-11-22 06:00',1),
('Mac2','2016-11-22 06:15',1),
('Mac2','2016-11-22 06:30',1),
('Mac2','2016-11-22 06:45',0),
('Mac2','2016-11-22 07:00',1);

;with CTE as
(
   select
   row_number() over (partition by Machine_Name order by [Time]) as rn,
   Machine_Name, [Time], Alarm
   from @SourceTable
),
RECURSIVE_CTE as 
(
   select Machine_Name, [Time], Alarm, rn, rn as rn_root, 0 as Relevancy
   from CTE
   where Alarm = 0
   UNION ALL
   select CTE.Machine_Name, CTE.[Time], CTE.Alarm, CTE.rn, R.rn_root, case when R.Relevancy = 100 then 100 else (R.Relevancy + 25) end
   from RECURSIVE_CTE R 
   JOIN CTE ON (R.Machine_Name = CTE.Machine_Name AND R.rn + 1 = CTE.rn AND CTE.Alarm = 1)
)
select R.Machine_Name, R.[Time], R.Alarm, R.Relevancy as [Alert_Relevancy(%)]
from RECURSIVE_CTE R
INNER JOIN (select Machine_Name, rn_root from RECURSIVE_CTE where Relevancy = 100 group by Machine_Name, rn_root) M
ON (R.Machine_Name = M.Machine_Name and R.rn_root = M.rn_root)
where R.Relevancy > 0
order by R.Machine_Name, R.[Time];
```

Returns:

```
Mac1    2016-11-22 06:15:00.000 1   25
Mac1    2016-11-22 06:30:00.000 1   50
Mac1    2016-11-22 06:45:00.000 1   75
Mac1    2016-11-22 07:00:00.000 1   100
Mac1    2016-11-22 07:15:00.000 1   100
Mac1    2016-11-22 07:30:00.000 1   100
Mac2    2016-11-22 05:45:00.000 1   25
Mac2    2016-11-22 06:00:00.000 1   50
Mac2    2016-11-22 06:15:00.000 1   75
Mac2    2016-11-22 06:30:00.000 1   100
```